# How to check a point is inside a surface in devdept eyeshot

Tags: c#, point, surface, eyeshot

I want to to see if a point is inside a trimmed surface or not. In the following pictures, I think that I have a surface which has a hole inside and also a point shown as red. How to check that the point is inside a trimmed surface or not.

I used the following code but it doesn't work. In this code `surfaceEntity` is a Surface object in which red point is inside. `pntEntity` is also an entity which is the red point in the below picture.

```
double x = (pntEntity.BoxMax.X + pntEntity.BoxMin.X) / 2;
double y = (pntEntity.BoxMax.Y + pntEntity.BoxMin.Y) / 2;


Point3D point3D = new Point3D(x, y, 0);

if (surfaceEntity.Trimming.IsPointInside(point3D))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inside");

}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not inside");
}
```

Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to compute 2D parametric coordinates of the point `point3D` using `surfaceEntity.Project()` or `surfaceEntity.ClosestPointTo()`. The resulting `u, v` values can then be used in the `Trimming.IsPointInside()` call.